# Get "User created/update/delete" using CEP

Tags: cumulocity

It is possible to have a stream of event in CEP related to a changes in the user API ?

What we want to achieve is create a device when a user is created.

Any Ideas ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Currently, Cumulocity only creates events for IoT data as described in the guide. Maybe you can hook that functionality to wherever the user is created?

Comment: @André I want to let the costumer uses the administration app to created or update users. I think one way to do it is create a plugin which does this task and remove the default user plugin in the administration app. right ? This will work for the Administration people.  But when the user change his password using his cockpit app (user setting ----> change password) I will not get this update!